# $(#divname).load(htmlcode) is not working in chrome & IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 

$(function() {
    $('#myList').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
    var text =  $(this).attr('id');
    var hashname = "#" + "content";
    var linkname = text + ".html";
        alert(text);

  $(hashname).load(linkname); 
    });
});
</script> 
 <ul id="myList" class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li id="about"> <a href="about.html">About us</a></li>
                            <li id="Services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                            <li id ="faq"><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>

                        </ul>
</head>

<body>
    Main Content
</div>
<br />

<div id="content"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I want to load header only once and want to dynamically load content by creating diff pages. Above code works well in mozilla but not workinf in Chrome or IE. Please help.

Below is Services.html

```
<p>This is dynamic content of service page</p>
<ul id="myList" class="dropdown-menu">

    <li><a href="services.html">Services</a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: What does "not working" mean? Error messages in the console? What do you expect to happen and what happens instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running these from `file:///`? IE doesn't allow file access when running locally and Chrome requires `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag to be set when you launch the browser. Firefox doesn't have these restrictions, so your project would work as you expect there.

To get around these issues, run your project in a local webserver.

Comment: Thanks. I tried it on server and its working on IE and Chrome. { --allow-file-access-from-files} can u pls let me know how to do this?

Comment: Create a shortcut for Chrome and add the flag after the executable name such as "C:\Users\petetnt\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --allow-file-access-from-files . Make sure that you close all the Chrome sessions (even the background tasks) when you restart/launch the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use HTML helpers instead url strings. That urls you have probably isn't correct.

Try to do something like this in your header page:

```
<head>
<title></title>
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('#myList').delegate('li', 'click', function() {
            var url = $(this).data('url');

            alert(text);

            $("#content").load(url); 
        });
    });
    </script> 

     <ul id="myList" class="dropdown-menu">
          <li id="about" data-url="@Url.Action("about", "myController")"> <a href="#">About us</a></li>
          <li id="Services" data-url=""><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li id ="faq" data-url="@Url.Action("faq", "myController")"><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>        
     </ul>
 </head>
```

But normally what is done is something like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
   <title></title>
   <script src="jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

   <ul id="myList" class="dropdown-menu">
     <li id="about"> <a href="@Url.Action("about", "myController")">About us</a></li>
     <li id="Services"><a href="#">Services</a></li>
     <li id ="faq"><a href="@Url.Action("faq", "myController")>FAQ</a></li>
   </ul>
  </head>

  <body>
    Main Content
    <br />

    <div id="content">
      @RenderBody()
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE to complete the my answer to your question:**

The code have some issues.

First,  tags have a href so, you the user click the code executes is suppose the page be redirected to that link reference and on the JS is trying to do the same, what is a little strange.

Second, some JS functions don't work for every browsers. However .load() is supported in IE and Chrome but the problem could be on the $(hashname) and the url that is passed on linkname by the reason I refered above (I'm not expert but I think normally HTTP GET request not supports that structure of url with .html in the end). So it's better to try my solution and give feedback

Comment: Can you explain why the original code works in some browsers? And is that C# or something? The question doesn't specify their server-side technology.

Comment: I used only C#, HTML and JavaScript with JQuery. I update my answer to answer to your questions too

Comment: *"Above code works well in mozilla but not workinf in Chrome or IE."*

Comment: Ok, I haven't saw that, sorry. However that is strange. That is the code orign? Some internet example?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. what is myController in your code?

Comment: wow, that your question let me concerned. I've never made websites without the MVC framework, and I also assumed that you were using this framework that makes web developers life much more easier. Sorry.. So 'myController' is a name that a gave to a fictitious controller, and a controller is a component of the MVC pattern